# Find the inverse of the functions

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I am dealing with the following problem for some time now:

Suppose you have these two functions:
$T_x^{-1}:\:x\:=\:x'\:+\:t_3\cdot \sin\left(\frac{2\cdot \:\pi \:\cdot \:y'}{t_1}\right)$ and $T_y^{-1}:\:y\:=\:y'\:+\:t_4\cdot \:\sin\left(\frac{2\cdot \:\:\pi \:\:\cdot \:\:x'}{t_2}\right)$, where $t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$ and $t_4$ are given constants.
From these two functions I want to find $T_x$ and $T_y$, so it means that I want $x'$ to depend only on $x$ and $y$, and I want $y'$ to depend only on $x$ and $y$.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that what you are asking for is possible?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Yes, I do. Actually Tx and Ty would be used to transform an image(distort the image a little bit).

Comment: OK, so, what is your reason for thinking it's possible to express $x'$ and $y'$ interms of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: The silence is deafening.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.